# RangePartitioner issue

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining two tables as below, the program stops at below log line and never proceeds.

> > > INFO SparkContext: Starting job: RangePartitioner at Exchange.scala:79

What might be the issue and possible solution? Is it the number of columsn thats is an issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Table 1 has 400 rows and 450 columns 
Table2 has  1000 rows and 100 columns

```
        val table1= myTable1.as('table1) 

        val table2= myTable2.as('table2) 

        val results= table1.join(table2,LeftOuter,Some("table1.Id".attr === "table2.id".attr )) 


       println(results.count())
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you see something on Spark UI, how many executors registered?

you can alternatively collect a jstack of the driver process?

Also If  you are running through submit please paste the exact command. I think 
you may use less number of executor threads.

I hope the below link will help

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Saving the intermediate RDDs to disk should resolve the issue.
rdd.saveAsTextFile("filename") or rdd.saveAsParquetFile("filename")